# I want to used md5 encryption method for password field in login form instead of existing bcrypt encryption method?

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I have completed login functionality using Auth middleware where is used a Bcrypt encryption method. Login functionality is works fine. But we need to handle set password functionality with having old password need to validate. But everytime Bcrypt method change the password string so the previous store bcrypt string of password in table is not match with the  manually enter password in  the set password form. So how to validate old password field if it will not match with existing saved passoword in the table.

```php
$credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
$user=Auth::attempt($credentials);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Laravel so you should use `Hash` in order to deal with passwords.

Here is all you need to know about it: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/hashing#basic-usage

In short you can create and verify the passwords in following ways:

#### Create hashed password to store in DB:

```
$hashedPassword = Hash::make($request->password);
```

#### Verify against existing password

```
if (Hash::check('entered-password-by-user', $hashedPassword)) {
    // The passwords match...
}
```

Of course dont forget to include Hash facade: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;`

#### md5 is ancient and very vulnerable way to go if you want to hash your passwords with it. It is HIGHLY DISCOURAGED!